# VisualForce Anchor Link

Tags: visualforce

What is the best way to implement an HTML anchor in VisualForce?

I would like to automatically scroll down to a specific section upon load of the page.

Ideally by going to something like

```
https://c.cs17.visual.force.com/apex/CP_MyAccount#documentsSection
```

It should automatically scroll down to the part where it has the anchor name of "documentsSection"

I've already tried both of these but no luck so far:

```
<a id="documentsSection" name="documentsSection">Documents</a>

<a name="documentsSection">Documents</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer! It works just fine when not in development mode.

https://c.cs17.visual.force.com/apex/CP_MyAccount?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1#documentsSection

For some reason I guess there are problems with the footer for the code but this solution now works for me!

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer as solution so community members know your question is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

If this is not natively supported in Visualforce, you could work around with javascript as illustrated [here](http://www.eltoro.it/ArticleViewer?id=a07A000000NPRhsIAH).

i.e. invoke a javascript function on load which sets `window.location.hash` to the anchor element grabbed from the URL.

Here is [another related post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/how-do-i-isolate-the-anchor-anchor-portion-of-a-url).

Answer (score 0):

If the `anchor` passed through URL is dynamic, the traditional way to pass `anchor` via hash might not work.

One workaround is to pass the `anchor` via parameter, and on page load, use javascript to scroll into the correct view.

Javascript:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    document.getElementById('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.myId}').scrollIntoView();
}
```

Element to be displayed:

```
<a id="{!myId}"></a>
```