# Returning a location hash in a page reference

Tags: visualforce, pagereference

I want to return a URL with a location hash in a page reference, but it appears that the system strips it out. Anybody know of a way to make this work without resorting to javascript? I can think of some ways to do it like that but I'd rather stick with standard functionality if possible.

This code:

```
 ApexPages.PageReference pr = new ApexPages.PageReference('/apex/APage#' + obj.Get('Id'));
 pr.SetRedirect(true);
 return pr;
```

Results in this URL in the browser:

`<<instance>>/apex/APage`

Comment: See: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/ as Andrew mentions - [Spring '14 PageReferences will support anchors](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/related/Visualforce+Spring14+Enhancements)!

Comment: I just posted an answer showing these methods, but it's not working for me right now! Will have to post when I get something functioning correctly.

Comment: Dang! Do you have the latest & greatest metadata version on all of the files involved with your page (including the page)? Looking forward to seeing this work using the PageReference class.

Comment: Yeah, all brand new stuff. Looks like Lance might have found the secret incantations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a Salesforce bug to me. I did some investigation on this:

```
ApexPages.PageReference pr = new ApexPages.PageReference('/apex/newTestPage');
pr.setAnchor('123');
System.debug(pr.getAnchor());
System.debug(pr.getUrl());
pr.SetRedirect(true);
return pr;
```

pr.getAnchor() returns 123 and pr.getUrl returns apex/newTestPage#123 with no issue. But on the returning page, it is still /apex/newTestPage

However, I changed the pr definition line to be:

```
ApexPages.PageReference pr = new ApexPages.PageReference('/apex/newTestPage?id=456');
```

The returning page becomes /apex/newTestPage?id=456#123, which contains the anchor.

So one easy walk around is just include something like ?id=456 will resolve your issue. It is strange though however works.

Comment: Nice one Lance, I had a quick crack with the methods but observed it not working, didn't think to try a parameter!

Comment: In case anyone is interested, this issue also came up when redirecting to an Angular JS page that includes a hash tag for routing purposes (ex. /apex/angularPage#/contact/:contactId). Adding a parameter before the hash tag fixes the issue here too (ex. /apex/angularPage?a=1#/contact/:contactId). (Apologies for the repost, there was a typo in the workaround example).