# Anchors stripped from VF pages in server-side redirects?

Tags: apex, visualforce, http

I'm unable to get a VF page to load with an anchor in the URL if I redirect server-side. After clicking a button, I'm doing a DML operation and redirecting to a VF page. In the redirect, I'd like to add an anchor to the URL which is handled by JS to open the page in edit mode once loaded.

**Redirecting page**

```
<apex:page controller="TestRedirectController" showHeader="true" sidebar="true" action="{!autoRedirect}">
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class TestRedirectController {
    public TestRedirectController() {}

    public PageReference autoRedirect() {
        PageReference pg = Page.TestRedirect2;
        pg.setAnchor('test');
        return pg;
    }
}
```

The resulting URL is `https://c.na17.visual.force.com/apex/testredirect2`. In contrast, when I redirect to the home page, I get `https://na17.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp#test`.

How can I redirect to a VF page with an anchor in the url?

**EDIT**

As suspected, it appears the anchor is lost during the redirection from `salesforce.com` to `visual.force.com`. Passing the full VF url to the PageReference works as expected:

```
public with sharing class TestRedirectController {
    public TestRedirectController() {}

    public PageReference autoRedirect() {
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('https://c.na17.visual.force.com/apex/testredirect2');
        pg.setAnchor('test');
        return pg;
    }
}
```

Since this is in a managed package, I would *love* to see workarounds to this problem that don't require having to pre-build the fully-qualified VF page URL.

Comment: what API version is your vf page?

Comment: I'm using v30...

Comment: hmmm...yeah, I am able to reproduce this exactly as you specify, even on API 31. is there a reason you don't want to just pass as a URL parameter?

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using a url parameter at the end. I'll file a case with support soon.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug. Please file a case with support. When I do exactly as you state, I get the exact same behavior.

In attempting to just pass a parameter, I left the `setAnchor` call in my code, and the anchor was preserved in the URL as follows:

```
https://c.na11.visual.force.com/apex/testredirect2?testparam=test#test
```

But even here, `PageReference.getAnchor()` is not successfully reading the anchor when I call it on CurrentPage.

The best workaround I can offer would be to pass something as a URL parameter. But I realize that certain JS frameworks look for specific anchors in the URL, and this might not be ideal.

I tried something really odd just because I was curious, which was to add `setAnchor` to the constructor of the controller of the redirect destination page, using a parameter to set the anchor. The result was strange in that it was readable by `getAnchor` in a getter method later, but didn't actually show up in the URL on the client in the address bar. That bit of ugly mess looked like this:

```
public TestRedirectController2() {//constructor
    String an = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('testparam'); 
    ApexPages.currentPage().setAnchor(an);
}

public String getAnchor(){
    String anchor = ApexPages.currentPage().getAnchor();
    System.debug('Anchor is: ' + anchor);
    //above outputs 'test' to log
    //method outputs 'test' to page when bound to
    return anchor; 
}
```

In any case, none of this seems to be acting as an API to work with URL anchors ought to by any reasonable measure. All signs point to bug.

Comment: For what it's worth there's [an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000a8R1AAI) and [this previous question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/how-do-i-isolate-the-anchor-anchor-portion-of-a-url) has some workarounds, too.